# I can't see my hard drive on Oracle Linux even though i've mounted it in Virtual Box

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, mount

I’m new to Linux. Currently installed an Oracle Linux (64-bit) on my machine. I basically want to be able to access files from my external hard drive that I’ve mounted with full access in the share folder in VirtualBox. I don’t have guest additions (perhaps that’s why its not working) but I can’t see the hard drive nor access the files.

If I can get step-by-step directions on how to go about it, I’d really appreciate it.

Comment: How have you mounted your hard drive?  Is it setup as a disk in VirtualBox or are you using the Shared Folders feature?

Answer (score 0):

> I basically want to be able to access files from my external hard
>   drive that I’ve mounted with full access in the share folder in
>   VirtualBox. I don’t have guest additions (perhaps that’s why its not
>   working) but I can’t see the hard drive nor access the files.

You need to install the VirtualBox guest additions and perhaps setup a USB filter to allow VirtualBox to see the USB hard drive and then the Oracle Linux guest OS will be able to see it. Here’s how I setup USB filters in VirtualBox VirtualBox in Mac OS X, but the general concept should work for any system running VirtualBox 5.0.

Basically since USB devices connected to a system running VirtualBox can be used by the system’s host OS as well as the guest OS on VirtualBox, VirtualBox has a “device filter” setup to allow you to select which USB devices should be used by the VirtualBox guest OS instead of the main system’s host OS.

First, shut down the virtual machine. Make sure the USB drive is plugged in an powered up so the host OS can recognize it. Now select the “Settings” for that virtual machine and choose the “Ports” option/tab which should look something like this:

[image]

In that area, select the USB part which should then look like this:

[image]

Make sure “Enable USB Controller” is checked and at least one of the USB controller types is selected. I would defer to “USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller” for now.

With that done you see that little icon that looks like a USB plug with a plus (`+`) over it? Click on that and select the USB drive from that menu. Once selected, it should show up in your list of items under “USB Device Filters.”

Once that’s done, just click “OK” and start up your virtual machine.